# What happened to my computer, and what are my recovery chances?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, troubleshooting

Today I was just using my computer as normal when it froze. Restarting, it froze on the windows logo (As in startup). Restarting again brought me to the "Windows failed to start" screen, where I tried to run startup repair.

After running for an hour saying "Repairing disk errors." the computer prompts to insert boot media and press any key. Diagnostics say that it can’t detect the internal HDD, and I received other errors by slightly altering these steps like 'Disk read error.'

When the computer starts, I can listen to it and hear the HDD spin up. There is no clicking or grinding sound, nor was there any warning to this occurrence. What might have happened, and assuming that did happen what are my chances of recovery?

My BIOS still sees the drive, as it’s serial and entry is still in the list of boot items, and says it is in the port, but the Diagnostics don’t, and I am currently lacking the equipment to test it on another computer. The computer is a Dell XPS 8500, and i've had it for about two years. The hard drive is Seagate, with a capacity of 1 TB. I don’t recall the exact model, and can't check at the moment.

Comment: Simplest would be just replace the drive & restore from a backup. Would you trust it again after this?

Comment: @Tetsujin I would, and this is my intention, however there are some critical files that were not included in the last backup a few weeks ago that would be very difficult to replace, and so at least partial recovery of the drive would be great.

Comment: My usual trick with hard-fail windows drives is get them into a USB enclosure & fix or dredge data off them from my Mac. Effective isolation from most system-based issues.

Comment: Ayye. I'd do the same. Slave the drive onto another machine, get as much data off as possible and chuck the disk. The ultimate lesson here is backup, backup and backup.

Comment: The term "slave" is offensive to some people and the preferred term is "secondary". If you're desparate to recover data off of it and it does not mount on a different computer, try [freezing the hard drive first](http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux). It could be an urban legend, but you can be the judge...

Comment: @sunk818 Huh. I never thought of it that way. I just thought the original PC engineers were just really kinky.

Comment: I guess there might be some PC engineers into S&M or bondage... ;)